# What's the oppposite of " if: :attribute? " (Rails4/active Record validations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my validations, I have already used once a conditional presence like

```
 validates :contact_name, presence: true
 validates :contact_adress,
              presence: true, if: :contact_name?,
```

Now I would like to do the contrary: condition the obligation of an attribute to the absence of the other attribute. If I let A empty, then B has to be filled and vice versa.

Would that work?

```
 validates :attribute_A, presence true, if:attribute_B!
 validates :attribute_B, presence true, if:attribute_A!
```

Comment: Won't unless do the magic??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unless` or [.blank?](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank?)

```
validates :attribute_A, presence true, if: :attribute_B.blank?
```

**OR**

```
validates :attribute_A, presence true, unless: :attribute_B
```

Answer (score 1):

From documentation of [`validates`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates)

> There is also a list of options that could be used along with validators:
>
> ...
>
> `:unless` - Specifies a method, proc or string to call to determine if the validation should not occur (e.g. `unless: :skip_validation`, or `unless: Proc.new { |user| user.signup_step <= 2 }`). The method, proc or string should return or evaluate to a `true` or `false` value.

However, it may be more clear to use `if:` with the help of [`Object#present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) or [`Object#blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F).